# AngularJS resource return empty json

Tags: json, resources, angularjs

Part of Code:

From Service part:

```
$resource('/Serializer/community/V1/latestPost/:start/:end,{
},{
    query: {method:'GET', 
            params:{start:new Date().getTime(), end:1}, 
            isArray:true}
})
```

From Controller part:

```
Post['latestPost_timestamp'].query({start: minTime,end:1},function (data) { 
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Result:

From console or link open on browser:
[3993,3983,3974,3964,3954,3944,3934,3926,3920,3910]

From controller:
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Why it return empty {} in controller? 
I would like it to be return in [3993,3983,3974,3964,3954,3944,3934,3926,3920,3910] but not 
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}].

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because a $resource should be an object and not a primitive, like a number in your case. If a resource could be a primitive, then you would have a problem with being able to both do this:

```
var posts = Post.query({start: minTime,end:1}, function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        var post = posts[i];
        // If post here should be equal to for example 3993 in
        // your JSON, you wouldn't be able to call any methods
        // on it. The following two statements sort if illustrates it:
        assert(post === 3993);
        post.$save();
    }
});
```

A resource is an object because of this, so you should probably change your server code to return something like `[{id: 3993}, {id: 3983}, ...]` instead, so that you can access the id by `post.id`.